# find the largest three Numbers on the array of int swift

Tags: swift, algorithm

I am trying to find the largest three Numbers on the array of int but my algorithms return the wrong result

input and output
largestthreeNumbers([141, 1, 17, -7, -17, -27, 18, 541, 8, 7, 7])

result
[141, 1, 17, 18, 541]
expected
[141, 18, 541]

```
func largestthreeNumbers(_ array:[Int]) ->[Int]{
        var first = 0
        var second = 0
        var thrid = 0
        var result = [Int]()
        if array.count < 3 {
            print("Invalid Input")
            return result
        }
        
        for i in 0 ..< array.count {
            if array[i] > first{
                thrid = second
                second = first
                first = array[i]
                result.append(first)
               
            }
            else if(array[i] > second){
                thrid = second
                second = array[i]
                result.append(second)
               
                
            }
            else if (array[i] > thrid){
                thrid = array[i]
                result.append(thrid)
           
            }
        }
        
        return result
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are appending to `result` inside the loop, every time you find a new maximum for `first`, `second` or `thrid`. This can happen more than 3 times. But the required array contains exactly 3 elements. Clearly, you shouldn't do add the `result` inside the loop.

You should only append to `result` at the end of the loop, the values `first`, `second` and `thrid`. You might as well just return the array literal `[first, second, thrid]` directly:

```
func largestThreeNumbers(_ array: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    var first = 0
    var second = 0
    var third = 0
    if array.count < 3 {
        print("Invalid Input")
        return []
    }
    
    for element in array {
        if element > first{
            third = second
            second = first
            first = element
           
        }
        else if element > second {
            third = second
            second = element
           
            
        }
        else if element > third {
            thrid = element
       
        }
    }
    return [first, second, third]
}
```

Comment: `i in 0 ..< array.count` -> `for i in array.indices`

Comment: Things like this really made me wish Swift's standard library had more datastructures, like a priority queue

Comment: @Alexander Me too :) `for element in array` would be better, don't you think?

Comment: Note that this would not preserve the order. This would result in [541, 141, 18] instead of [141, 18, 541]

Comment: @LeoDabus Oh I see. I didn't realise the importance of the order in the result array until you said "preserve"!

Answer (score 5):

If you need to preserve the order of the elements you can sort the collection elements indices by its values get the last 3 indices of the highest elements, sort them and map the corresponding elements:

```
let numbers = [141, 1, 17, -7, -17, -27, 18, 541, 8, 7, 7]

let largestNumbers = numbers
    .indices
    .sorted { numbers[$0]<numbers[$1] }
    .suffix(3)
    .sorted()
    .map{ numbers[$0] }  // [141, 18, 541]
```

If the resulting order is not important You can simply sort the elements in descending order and get the first n elements:

```
let largestNumbers = numbers.sorted(by: >).prefix(3)   // [541, 141, 18]
```

if you are dealing with a large collection you can check [SortedPrefix](https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms/blob/3864606e00177c3438db075df56659cdfbc01ca8/Sources/Algorithms/SortedPrefix.swift) algorithm from Apple's swift-algorithms on GitHub as mention in this SO post on [how to get the top 3 maximum values in a Swift dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65746299/how-do-you-find-the-top-3-maximum-values-in-a-swift-dictionary/65746321#65746321)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do this. Heavily inspired by Sweeper's approach, but built in a way that would let you drop in a priority queue data structure in the future, when one eventually (hopefully) gets add to the standard library.

```swift
struct PriorityQueueOf3<T: Comparable> {
    public private(set) var values: (T, T, T) // Ordered largest to smallest
    
    mutating func insert(_ newValue: T) {
        if newValue > values.0      { (values.0, values.1, values.2) = (newValue, values.0, values.1) }
        else if newValue > values.1 { (values.0, values.1, values.2) = (values.0, newValue, values.1) }
        else if newValue > values.2 { (values.0, values.1, values.2) = (values.0, values.1, newValue) }
    }
    
    func toArray() -> [T] {
        [values.0, values.1, values.2]
    }
}

func largestThreeNumbers(_ array: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    if array.count < 3 {
        fatalError("Invalid Input") // TODO: Handle this error better
    }
    
    var queue = PriorityQueueOf3<Int>(values: (0, 0, 0))
    
    for element in array {
        queue.insert(element)
    }
    
    return queue.toArray()
}


let input = Array(1...10).shuffled()
let result = largestThreeNumbers(input)
print(result)
```

If you want to preserve the initial ordering, you can do something like this:

```swift
struct IndexedValue<T: Comparable>: Comparable {
    let index: Int
    let value: T
    
    static func == (lhs: IndexedValue, rhs: IndexedValue) -> Bool { lhs.value == rhs.value }
    static func <  (lhs: IndexedValue, rhs: IndexedValue) -> Bool { lhs.value <  rhs.value }
}

func largestThreeNumbers(_ array: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    if array.count < 3 {
        fatalError("Invalid Input") // TODO: Handle this error better
    }
    
    let dummy = IndexedValue(index: 0, value: 0)
    var queue = PriorityQueueOf3(values: (dummy, dummy, dummy))
    
    for (element, index) in zip(array, array.indices) {
        queue.insert(IndexedValue(index: index, value: element))
    }
    
    return queue.toArray()
        .sorted(by: { $0.index < $1.index }) // restore the original ordering
        .map(\.value) // discard the indices
}


let input = Array(1...10).shuffled()
let result = largestThreeNumbers(input)

print(input)
print(result)
```

This is really optimizing for large data sets, but it's not very practical over all. A simple sort would be `O(log(n) * n)`, whereas this is just `O(n)`. You'd need a really large input to make this worth the complexity.

Comment: You might be interest in this https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms/blob/3864606e00177c3438db075df56659cdfbc01ca8/Sources/Algorithms/SortedPrefix.swift

Comment: @LeoDabus I wonder what the best data structure would be to hold the "sorted prefix". Perhaps a tree, with `O(log(n))` insertions, though ofc that would need a really large prefix size to be worth while

Comment: Note that sortedPrefix wont preserve the order of the elements

Comment: @LeoDabus It would, if you used a `IndexValue` wrapper like this

Answer (score 0):

```
var numberArray  = [5,2,3,1,7,4,6]
var firstLargest = numberArray[0]
var secondLargest = numberArray[0]
var thirdLargest = numberArray[0]
var result = [Int]()

for i in numberArray {
    if firstLargest < i {
        firstLargest = i
    }
}
result.append(firstLargest)

for j in numberArray {
    if j != firstLargest && secondLargest < j {
        secondLargest = j
    }
}
result.append(secondLargest)


for k in numberArray {
    if k != firstLargest && k != secondLargest && thirdLargest < k {
        thirdLargest = k
    }
}
result.append(thirdLargest)
print(result)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

In Java

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
 
 int[] arr={7,18,92,72,29,57};
 
 int first,second,third;
 
 first=second=third=Integer.MIN_VALUE;
 
 for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
   if(arr[i]>first){
     third=second;
     second=first;
     first=arr[i];
   }else if(arr[i]>second){
     third=second;
     second=arr[i];
     
   }else{
     third=arr[i];
   }
 }
 System.out.println(""+first+"\t"+second+"\t"+third);

}
```

}

Comment: Does it add something new or advantageous to the other 4 answers? Please, could you [edit] and add a small explanation to your code.